# How to browse open a file or folder python

Tags: file, browser, directory, pyqt5

I am familiar with `QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory` and `QFileDialog.getOpenFileName` but I want a way to click my browse button to open my file explorer, and return the path of either the folder or file selected.

Here is some example code. Is it possible to get the two `getSelectedItem()` functions into one method call?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QFileDialog


class AppDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.btn = QPushButton('Browse', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print(self.getSelectedItem()))

    def getSelectedItem(self):
        self.browseInput = str(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self))
        print(self.browseInput)

    # def getSelectedItem(self):
    #     self.browseInput = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self))
    #     print(self.browseInput)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = AppDemo()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by "my file explorer"? If you're referring to dedicated program (like Total Commander) it *might* be possible, depending on the program and the fact that it allows such interaction, but if you mean the OS file browser, it might be harder (or even impossible, depending on the OS).

Comment: @musicamante I am referring to the OS file browser. I wasn't sure if there was a simple method that I was missing, or if was even possible.

Comment: On Windows and MacOS you can open the file browser to a specific path and automatically select a file (at least on Windows), but that has nothing to do with PyQt. But since you also want to get back the selected file, that wouldn't be very useful. So, long story short, you can't - at least not in a good, easy and reliable way.

Answer (score 0):

You want the file name and the folder that the file was in, correct? I think this should work:

```
    def getSelectedItem(self):
         self.browseInput = str(QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self))
         print(self.browseInput)
         print(self.browseInput.split('/')[-2])
```